# Strapi v4.1.7 and Flutter v2.10.4 | How to Build CRUD Application

Tags: flutter, strapi

Please explain a simple example of CRUD operations, because after updating the **new flutter (v2.10) and Strapi (v4.1.7)** , I did not find resources that explain this at all, whether in English or Arabic, All existing **Resources** are old and explain to **old versions** , and I no longer have the ability to make successful communication between them in these four operations because of this update, which led to a change in the format of the codes used for it
plz help me
and thank you

```
GET http://localhost:1337/api/restaurants
        
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "attributes":{
            "title":"sport articale1",
            "source":"cnn",
            "description":",jkhjhjhgjhgjg",
            "url":"url",
            "publishedDate":"2022-03-23",
            "content":"vnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn\nhkhjhkj\niuhuihug\nuhih\ny7iuyhuhjhjkh\n8y8yuihjhjhkhj9o7guyfu8ygo\nliuhljkjgyoih",
            "createdAt":"2022-03-21T14:28:36.087Z",
            "updatedAt":"2022-03-21T14:28:37.638Z",
            "publishedAt":"2022-03-21T14:28:37.634Z",
            "image":{
               "data":{
                  "id":5,
                  "attributes":{
                     "name":"index (1).jpeg",
                     "alternativeText":"index (1).jpeg",
                     "caption":"index (1).jpeg",
                     "width":840,
                     "height":548,
                     "formats":{
                        "thumbnail":{
                           "name":"thumbnail_index (1).jpeg",
                           "hash":"thumbnail_index_1_ddbc5b6f38",
                           "ext":".jpeg",
                           "mime":"image/jpeg",
                           "path":null,
                           "width":239,
                           "height":156,
                           "size":16.87,
                           "url":"/uploads/thumbnail_index_1_ddbc5b6f38.jpeg"
                        },
                        "medium":{
                           "name":"medium_index (1).jpeg",
                           "hash":"medium_index_1_ddbc5b6f38",
                           "ext":".jpeg",
                           "mime":"image/jpeg",
                           "path":null,
                           "width":750,
                           "height":489,
                           "size":155.43,
                           "url":"/uploads/medium_index_1_ddbc5b6f38.jpeg"
                        },
                        "small":{
                           "name":"small_index (1).jpeg",
                           "hash":"small_index_1_ddbc5b6f38",
                           "ext":".jpeg",
                           "mime":"image/jpeg",
                           "path":null,
                           "width":500,
                           "height":326,
                           "size":70.99,
                           "url":"/uploads/small_index_1_ddbc5b6f38.jpeg"
                        }
                     },
                     "hash":"index_1_ddbc5b6f38",
                     "ext":".jpeg",
                     "mime":"image/jpeg",
                     "size":202.38,
                     "url":"/uploads/index_1_ddbc5b6f38.jpeg",
                     "previewUrl":null,
                     "provider":"local",
                     "provider_metadata":null,
                     "createdAt":"2022-03-21T14:28:26.663Z",
                     "updatedAt":"2022-03-21T14:28:26.663Z"
                  }
               }
            },
            "category":{
               "data":{
                  "id":1,
                  "attributes":{
                     "name":"sports",
                     "createdAt":"2022-03-21T14:24:26.930Z",
                     "updatedAt":"2022-03-21T14:24:29.087Z",
                     "publishedAt":"2022-03-21T14:24:29.086Z"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "meta":{
      "pagination":{
         "page":1,
         "pageSize":25,
         "pageCount":1,
         "total":7
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: So it worked on previous versions of Flutter and Strapi? If you can’t debug the problem, try downgrade of Strapi and Flutter

Comment: yes,it worked on previous versions....but i need to work on new version because there is a different http response

Comment: so you need to find the difference in those responses, try downgrading Strapi, save it's response and compare it with the new one using some diff tool, it will help you to adjust Flutter parsing